# Client ws can't connect to nodejs websocket server hosted on Azure app service?

Tags: node.js, azure, websocket, ws

Anybody knows how to setup a websocket server nodejs (npm package ws) app service on Azure ?
My ws client can't connect to the ws server... Thank you for any hint!

[image: azure app service screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you missed something to start up your application. I write a sample demo for you,the project secture is simple just like below:
[image]

Code of `wstest.js`:

```
const WebSocket = require('ws');
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080

const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ port });

wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {
  ws.on('message', function incoming(message) {
    console.log('received: %s', message);
  });

  ws.send('something from server');
});
```

I use vs code to deploy this project directly, so that this project will under folder : `/home/site/wwwroot/` so we should use node command to start up it, just as below:

[image]

After deploying it, let's test it from local:
[image]

Comment: thanks for your reply, it is useful.
Apparently it is a SSL problem, although azurewebsites.net has a valid certificate.
I just changed from a Free Service Plan(F1) to a Basic Service Plan(P1), now it works with your code.
I still have an error with my C++ websocket client, investigating...

Comment: @BruceLANE,Glad to know that my solution is helpful. Please click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in to accept it as an answer, so that it will help others and close this query : )

Comment: @StanleyGong any chance you still have the package.json file with you as I am getting strange errors when client trying to connect to server. I have followed all the steps yo have shown here.. The  error : throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: Unexpected server response: 403
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:\Development\wsazure\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:604:7)  Thank you

Comment: my package.json contents {
  "name": "socket-server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/socket.io": "^2.1.10",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "socket.io": "^2.3.0",
    "websocket": "^1.0.34",
    "ws": "^7.4.5"
  }
}